# AWS Lambda Nodejs async.waterfall not executing MQTT Function

Tags: asynchronous, aws-lambda, waterfall

I am trying to use `async.waterfall` in the exports handler, and call functions sequentially. One of the function is related to MQTT message publishing. While the functions are being called, but when the MQTT function gets called, it just stops and not calls the require ('MQTT').

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
        var async = require('async');

        async.waterfall([
            function(callback) {
                retrieveEmailId(apiAccessToken,callback)
            },
            function(emailId, callback) {
                retrieveDeviceDetails(callback)
            },
            function(deviceDetail, callback) {
                publishMsg(callback)
            }

        ], function(err, result) {
            if (err) console.log('Error :: \n' + err);
        });
    }

    function retrieveEmailId(accessToken, callback) {
        var getEmailFromAlexaProfileObj = require('./GetEmailFromAlexaProfile');
        getEmailFromAlexaProfileObj.doIt(accessToken, function(returnVal) {
            console.log(returnVal);
            callback(null, returnVal)
        });
    }

    function retrieveDeviceDetails(callback) {
        var getDevcieDetailsObj = require('./GetDevcieDetails');
        getDeviceDetailsObj.doIt(null, function(returnVal) {
            console.log(returnVal);
            callback(null, returnVal)
        });
    }

    function publishMsg() {
        var mqtt = require('mqtt');

        var options = {
            clientId: "xxx",
            username: "yyy",
            password: "zzz",
            clean: true
        };

        var client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://xxx.com", options)

        client.on("connect", function () {              
            client.publish('xxx/yyy/L1', "1", options);             
            client.end();
        });         
    }
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the code locally using "lambda-local"? Does that sequence of call work along with the last one that is MQTT? What have you noticed when you invoke "require('mqtt')" within lambda?

Comment: The code works absolutely fine when run locally using lambda-local, with the same sequence of functions. When it is called with AWS, while the code does call the MQTT function but as soon as it reaches "require('MQTT')", it just ends with no errors in the cloudwatch logs. This is thereby not giving any clue what may be the cause.

Comment: have you removed context.suceeed()? This sometimes causes the control goes away by the time the other function being executed and completed.

Comment: Yes even after removing context.succeed(), the MQTT is not getting successfully called. Looking forward for your expert advise ...

Comment: which version of npm mqtt used? the latest one is  mqtt@2.18.8.

Comment: Yes used the latest version of mqtt@2.18.8

Answer (score 0):

Problem got resolved if the require variable is done prior to exports.handler.

for example....

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var async = require('async');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

....
}